# three.js rotate planes so they are always perpendicular to the camera axis without changing z rotation

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to add clouds to my scene using the approach in https://codepen.io/teolitto/pen/KwOVvL, which is to make a large number of plane objects at random positions that each rotate continuously around their z axes.

But I would like to be able to move my camera, change its target, etc., and still have the cloud planes look right.

What I need to do is rotate the planes so that as the camera moves and changes target, the cloud planes stay perpendicular to the camera's axis.  And I need to do this without changing the planes' rotation around their own z-axis, because otherwise that would break the cloudlike appearance.

I've tried `cloudplane.lookAt(camera.position)` but of course that doesn't work.  It aims all of the planes at the camera, instead of making them all perpendicular to the camera axis. It also sets the object's z-axis, so the clouds don't evolve.

Any advice is appreciated.  (I'm new to three.js, so if I have some of the terminology wrong, I apologize for that.)

Edit:

Setting the cloudplane's rotation.x and rotation.y to match the camera's rotation.x and rotation.y seems to get me pretty close, but it doesn't quite get there - its still possible to orbit the camera to a position where the clouds are all invisible because they're all parallel to the camera.

Comment: Is `cloudplane.quaternion.copy( camera.quaternion );` what you want?

Comment: Won't that also adjust the cloudplane's rotation in its own z-axis though?  I'm new to three.js, and the operation of its coordinate system and many options for adjusting position and orientation (quaternions, rotation, euler, etc.) are pretty mysterious to me.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it, it makes the clouds freeze, so they don't rotate around their own z axis as they need to.

Comment: Oh, I see. Try `mesh.rotation.order = 'YXZ';`. Then in the render loop, `radians += 0.01; mesh.quaternion.copy( camera.quaternion ); mesh.rotation.z = radians;`. Alternatively, you can use a `Sprite` and set `sprite.material.rotation = radians`;

Comment: If I use sprites, then all of the objects face the camera.  I need them all to be parallel with each other, perpendicular to the camera's axis.

Comment: Sprites are rendered parallel to screen-space.

Comment: Sprites aren't perpendicular to the camera -- they face the camera.  https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Sprite

Comment: The docs are not correct.

Comment: Hah! thanks :) Not sure that resolves the question, but I appreciate the insight.